# echo last character of text file in Unix/Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I need to see the last characters of bunch of text files (or alternatively test whether they are "}" and give a list of files that test negative ). Is there an easy way to do this from the command line.

(Ideally the solution works without reading the whole file from the start because in addition to there being many they can also be quite large.

P.S.: Any answer would be great but I would really appreciate if the function and syntax of everything in the answer can be fully explained.

Comment: You can use the `tail` command to get the last line and check if the line ends with `}`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done fairly easily with `tail` and then string indexing in bash. For example, you obtain the last line in a file with, `tail -n1 file`. You will need to store the line in a variable using *command-substitution*, e.g.

```
lastln=$(tail -n1 file)
```

Then it is simply a matter of indexing the last characters, e.g.

```
echo ${lastln:(-1)}
```

(**note:** when indexing from the end of the string, you must put the offset (e.g. `-1` in parenthesis `(-1)` -- or -- you must leave a space **before** the `-1`, e.g. `echo ${lastln: -1}` is also valid.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for file in file1 file2; do tail -n 1 "$file" | grep -q '}$' || echo "$file"; done
```

where you should replace `file1 file2` with the list of files you want to analyze, e.g. `*` or the like. Now what happens here? The outer part

```
for file in file1 file2; do ...; done
```

is a simple loop over the files, where inside the loop, you can refer to the current file as $file. Then,

```
tail -n 1 "$file"
```

prints the last line of the given file and

```
| grep -q '}$'
```

redirects the output to grep (turned into silent mode with `-q`), which looks for '}' immediatly followed by the end of the line ($). The return value of this command can be used to chain another action: when grep returns non-zero (indicating failure, i.e., the pattern is not matched), the last part

```
|| echo "$file"
```

is executed, resulting in the list of files you need.

Comment: Wow, thanks! And thanks for having the patience to explain the steps. P.S. I actually asked for returning a list that tested negative, i.e. I meant not matching }, so to change that I would replace && by || , right?